# Should an OAuth2.0/OpenIdConnect client be Used to connect to multiple Resources?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

The situation is thus: I have one application (let's call it the manager app because I'm really not sure how to assign the Resource and Client in this situation) that will be accessing data from an unspecified number (between 0 and infinity) of other applications (I'll call these the provider apps). The manager app will be using OAuth2.0 to authorize with the provider apps so that it can securely gather the needed data.

All of the apps (both my manager app and all of the provider apps) have been registered as "clients" (I'm not sure I'm using the term correctly here) with our in-house OAuth2.0 Authorization Server. Each of these clients has been assigned scopes for which they are permitted to access other applications.

The primary question is:

**"Do I need to register a unique OAuth2.0 Client for the manager app to preform it's authorization with each of the manager apps, or do I use a single OAuth2.0 Client for the manager app that works for authorizing with every provider app based solely on the scopes assigned to it?"**

Furthermore, for at least one of the provider apps, more information than just the scopes is needed for proper Authorization (essentially this information allows me to identify which tenant the Authorization is attempting to communicate with). In the past, I used HTTP headers to pass this information, however the manager application is not capable of adding headers to the data requests, nor does it have a concept of the exact information I need. Fortunately, the manager application does have access to a pair of values that can be combined to determine the critical information, however it still cannot add these values to the HTTP headers.

Question 2 is:

**"I'm expecting to use claims in the JWT to provide the necessary information, but is this the correct method, and if it is, does this change whether I need unique manager app clients for each provider app?"**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to at least have separate logic for each. I would suggest using two separate clients to keep it clean, but it's not necessary as long as you're handling, in your app, the right calls and claims analysis to the proper places. This can easily get confusing and hard to debug.

Comment: You have an oauth server, the provider apps are the resource servers, and your manager is app is the client. If the provider apps don't know about each others' registered clients and don't require uniqueness, then it's not necessary to set up your manager app as "separate clients", but this can get confusing if you don't. On the flip side, auditing across those provider apps/resource servers might be easier to see the same client making calls.